# Converting xls to csv but unable to close excel using vbs

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I am using a VBScript to convert a xls file to csv.  The process seems to be working how I need it except after the file gets converted my script won't close Excel.  Both files remain open in excel preventing them from being updated or opened by other apps.

Here is the script I am using:

```
Set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelObj.DisplayAlerts = True
ExcelObj.Visible  = false
ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open "P:\Pro2010\folder\Ovations\ovations.xls"
ExcelObj.Workbooks(1).SaveAs "P:\Pro2010\folder\Ovations\edited\company-JULY-TEST.csv", 6
OverwriteExisting 
oExcel.Quit
```

When I open the file in Excel after the script has run it says "The file is in use by 'Another user'.  Open a read Only?'

Comment: After your "SaveAs" you could try closing it? `ExcelObj.Workbooks(1).Close`

Comment: That didn't work either.  Still getting the same error. I hanged the visible tag to True and It leaves Excel open

Comment: Did you use Task Manager to kill the hidden instance of Excel?

Comment: Yes.  Then I can edit the file or delete it

Comment: I just noticed... shouldnt this line say: `ExcelObj.Quit` instead of oExcel?

Comment: Nice! That was it!  Thanks for the help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
oExcel.Quit
```

to this

```
ExcelObj.Quit
```